# Powershell Invoke-WmiMethod to execute bat file on server 2003

Tags: batch-file, powershell, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to execute a bat file on a different server that copies files to several other servers.  I can get to the bat file and execute it just fine.  But the commands in the bat file don't run.  I know the bat file executes because I added an echo > text.txt statement, and that worked.
Here is what I have:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ComputerName $serverName -Credential $Credentials -ArgumentList "cmd /c D:\startBat.bat"
```

Here is the bat file on the other server

```
d:
cd \path\path2
echo "asdf" > text.txt
copy /Y file.zip \\serv5\e$\temp\temp1
copy /Y file.zip \\serv4\e$\temp\temp1
copy /Y file.zip \\serv3\e$\temp\temp1
copy /Y file.zip \\serv2\e$\temp\temp1
copy /Y file.zip \\serv1\e$\temp\temp1


copy /Y file2.zip \\serv5\e$\temp\temp1
copy /Y file2.zip \\serv4\e$\temp\temp1
copy /Y file2.zip \\serv3\e$\temp\temp1
copy /Y file2.zip \\serv2\e$\temp\temp1
copy /Y file2.zip \\serv1\e$\temp\temp1
```

I'm at a loss as to what's going on here.  I don't think it's a permission thing because I can get a service as a wmi object just fine and start, stop the service all I want. So I'm fairly certain my credentials are good.

thanks!

Comment: Does the wmi method work locally?

Comment: Yes, wmi works.  Locally and remotely.  It's weird that the bat on the other server will write garbage to a text file but skips copy operations.

Comment: Have you tried running a powershell script remotely?

Comment: I'm not at a computer to try it, but what happens if you as a net use prior to copying the files

Comment: I can't run powershell remotely in this case.  Net use makes no difference.